# How to get GPS location NMEA from android phone to PC situated 100 meters away?

Tags: java, android, gps

How to get GPS location NMEA from android phone to PC situated 100 meters away?
I don't wish to buy a GPS device and want the phone to work as a GPS device. How can i do that? I want the phone to send its NMEA log files or any other gps log format into my Computer which is situated more than 100 meters away from my phone, hence i cannot use USB cord or Bluetooth.. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both your PC and the phone have Internet connections.

Application on the phone send it's location to a central server, your PC pulls that data from the server.

There are probably several applications that exist to do this...

Comment: found a device on google play, 'gpsLogger', in that ftp settings lets u sent the data to any ftp server directly.